# Express 4.2.0 server not working on Heroku while using primus

Tags: heroku, express, primus

The server works fine running locally with express and primus.  However my routes fail when hosted on heroku.  If I remove the primus wrapper around my routes it works both locally and on heroku.

```
var express = require('express'),
    Primus = require('primus'),
    Emitter = require('primus-emitter'),
    compress = require('compression'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    List = require('./models/list'),
    app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    router = express.Router();

/**
 * Load controllers.
 */

var apiController = require('./controllers/api');

/**
 * API keys.
 */

var secrets = require('./config/secrets');

/**
 * Mongoose configuration.
 */

mongoose.connect(secrets.db);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function() {
    console.error('✗ MongoDB Connection Error. Please make sure MongoDB is running.');
});

app
    .use(compress())
    .use(bodyParser())
    .use('/api', router)
    .use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

/**
 * server
 */

var server = require('http').createServer(app),
    primus = new Primus(server, { transformer: 'websockets', parser: 'JSON' });

primus.use('emitter', Emitter);

server.listen(port);
console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port);

primus.on('connection', function (spark) {
    var listsRoute = router.route('/list');

    listsRoute.get(function(req, res) {

        List.find(function(err, obj) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }

            primus.send('obj', obj);
            res.json(obj);
        });
    });
});
```

Im using:

- Express 4.2.0
- Primus 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to change the hostname primus was listening to on the client side from localhost to my heroku app url.